# C Primer plus chapter 6 exercise 3

Tags: c

What they are asking to do it to print:

```
F
FE
FED
FEDC
FEDCB
FEDCBA
```

I was able to print:

```
F
FF
FFF
FFFF
FFFFF
```

with this code:

```
int main()
{
    int count, count2;

    char letterToPrint = 'F';

    for (count = 0; count < 5; count++)
    {
        for (count2 = 0; count2 <= count; count2++)
        {
            printf("%c", letterToPrint);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Is there something I can add in the second `for` loop to print the previous letter and then decrement it, or does this take another loop?

Comment: why don't you try your suggestion and decrement the previous letter, just don't forget to set it to F again in the start of each loop

Comment: There is something. Just change `latterToPrint` in the `printf` call to something else, derived from `count2`

Comment: This is HOMEWORK .. I removed the homework tag as its obsolete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change the value of `letterToPrint` in your inner loop and reset it at the start of the outer loop:

```
int main()
{
    int count, count2;
    for (count = 0; count < 5; count++)
    {
        char letterToPrint = 'F'; // MOVED
        for (count2 = 0; count2 <= count; count2++)
        {
            printf("%c", letterToPrint--);
            //                        ^^
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks allot! just to know, except of this error i had, is that looks like a decent C code?

Comment: Yes, your post looked like very decent C code.  There are some extremely minor stylistic issues - its more usual to use single letter variables like `i`, `j` for loop counters and you used a lot of white space - but your code is clear and implements a sensible algorithm.  If this is homework, you certainly shouldn't be marked down for the content or style of this code.

Answer (score 5):

Remember that a character in C (both character literals such as `'F'` and the `char` type) are normal integer values, and as such you can perform normal arithmetic with them and e.g. loop from `'F'` to `'A'`.

Like this:

```
for (int i = 'F'; i >= 'A'; i--)
{
    for (int c = 'F'; c >= i; c--)
        printf("%c", c);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: thank is a very good point and example! thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Just change `printf("%c", letterToPrint);` to `printf("%c", letterToPrint - count);`

You should probably use `putchar` instead of `printf` though, giving:
 `putchar(letterToPrint - count);`

Answer (score 2):

Just for the heck of it:

```
for(int i = 20; i >= 0 ; i-=4)
{
    printf("%X\n", 0xFEDBCA >> i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even generalise this solution for any character since number of lines you are going to print is 
**(int)('F'-'A')**

```
void printCharPattern(char startChar)
{
int count, count2;
char letterToPrint = starChar;
int no_of_lines = (int)startChar-(int)'A'+1;

for (count = 0; count < no_of_lines; count++)
{   
    letterToPrint = start_char;
    for (count2 = 0; count2 <= count; count2++)
    {
        printf("%c", letterToPrint--);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

decrement letterToPrint in the inner loop and initialize it in the outer one.

Answer (score 0):

declare another char differLetter
after the first for loop say differLetter=latterToPrint
printf differLetter instead of latterToPrint

Answer (score 0):

And if the given letter is 'G' or 'Z'? A more generic algorithm

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char letter = 'F';

  int i=0,j;
  do {
    for (j=0 ; j<=i ; j++) printf("%c", letter-j);
    printf("\n");
  } while (letter-i++ > 'A');

  return 0;
}
```